# how to get the totalRecords to display during the pagination

Tags: pagination, datatables

Im using the datatables plugin for pagination.
I'm trying to get my server-side pagination working, however to start with, im facing the issue of not been able to display the totalRecords entires in the 'Showing 1 to 15 of 15 entries' text. im using this to display all the records:

```
var resultsTable = tableEl.dataTable( { 
 "aaData": tableData,
     "aoColumns": tableColumns,
     "aaSorting": [[1,'asc']],
    // "bServerSide": true,
      "processing": true,
     "serverSide": true,
     "sAjaxDataProp": "api/1.0/accounts",
     "bProcessing": true,
     "pagingType": "simple_numbers", 
     "bLengthChange": false,
     "bAutoWidth": false,
     "bScrollCollapse": true,
     "iTotalRecords": 34,
     "iTotalDisplayRecords":15,
     "iDisplayLength": 15
      } );
```

but it still shows me 'Showing 1 to 15 of 15 entries' instead of 'Showing 1 to 15 of 34 entries'. Any idea what im i missing here?Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that `iTotalRecords` and `iTotalDisplayRecords` are values that are returned from the server, not values that you set during initialisation.

Can you add the code that generates the server-side data? How are you actually paging that source data?

In your `accounts` method, you should be returning a json object that looks something like this:

```
return Json(new
  {
     param.sEcho,
     iTotalRecords = totalRecords,
     iTotalDisplayRecords = totalFilteredRecords,
     aaData = result
}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Where `iTotalRecords` is the total, unfiltered record count and `iTotalDisplayRecords` is the filtered record count. `result` contains 15 rows of data because at this point you will have already performed the paging query using the datatable parameters `iDisplayStart` and `iDisplayLength` to generate the data.  You now have all the information to correctly display the page when you return this json object to the datatable.